# How to detect tablet(any) requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
 {
     Response.Redirect("/mobile/Login.htm");`
 }
```

To detect mobiles but same times it detect Tablet like mobile, i need function that check if there Tablet or function that check the size of screen of the device.

Thank"s that work i used ScreenPixelsWidth  and ScreenPixelsHeight this is the code if any need it

```
 int wight = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth;
                int height = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight;

                if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && wight < 720 && height<1280)
            {
               Response.Redirect("/mobile/Login.htm");
            }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @acb that link doesn't apply in this case. This is a browser we are talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ScreenPixelsWidth and ScreenPixelsHeight (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.aspx) and you can define a threshold in which you consider whether the regular or the mobile version should be rendered.

There are many more ways to tackle this issue but since you are already using the HttpBrowserCapabilities class, you might as well use these 2 properties.

Comment: Thank"s that work i used ScreenPixelsWidth  and ScreenPixelsHeight this is the code if any need it    `int wight = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth;
                int height = Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight;

                if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && wight < 720 && height<1280)
            {
               Response.Redirect("/mobile/Login.htm");
            }`

Comment: I think way holds up better than agent string pattern matching.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar issue and tried using: 
    HttpContext.Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth

However this always returned a value of 640 pixels regardless of device (iphone or ipad).  I resolved the issue by creating a static method to inspect the User Agent string instead.

```
public class DeviceHelper
{
    public static bool IsTablet(string userAgent, bool isMobile)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex("ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle|nexus");
        bool isTablet = r.IsMatch(userAgent) && isMobile;
        return isTablet;
    }
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
if(DeviceHelper.IsTablet(Request.UserAgent, Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice))
     return Redirect("..."); // redirect to tablet url
```

Comment: does this mean that `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` returns true for both phones and tablets?

Comment: @IanCampbell yes, because you can carry them both in one hand!  More likely MS left it up to extensions like [51Degrees.mobi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/51Degrees.mobi) to pick up the slack _(although I think the free version of that addon still reports everything as mobile)_

Comment: Regex should be instantiated in that way: `Regex r = new Regex("ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle|nexus", **RegexOptions.IgnoreCase**);`

Comment: Nice solution. Almost one year later an update on the RegEx: `Regex r = new Regex("Tablet|iPad|PlayBook|BB10|Z30|Nexus 10|Nexus 7|GT-P|SCH-I800|Xoom|Kindle|Silk|KFAPWI", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`. This was also tested with Chrome DevTools Device Mode.

Comment: So with this solution we gotta update the regex as and when new devices come in market.. Keeping track of all devices world wide would be a pain..

Answer (score 2):

ScreenPixelsWidth always returns 640 so is not useful in detecting phones. I found this works:

```
public static bool IsPhoneDevice(this HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase Browser)
{
      return (Browser.IsMobileDevice && Browser.CanInitiateVoiceCall);
}
```

Comment: Browser.CanInitiateVoiceCall is returning false on mobile Chrome for Android. I tried Galaxy S5 and Pixel 3.

Comment: I ran into this same problem w/ my Android cellphone where CanInitiateVoiceCall returned false in Chrome browser.